# cygwin make error: recipe for target 'MalderMain.o' failed

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I got a problem when compiling a program in Cygwin using `make`
and here's the error notice :

```
g++ -O2 -fopenmp -Wall -I/opt/local/include -Wno-write-strings -Iadmixtools_src -Iadmixtools_src/nicksrc -o MalderMain.o -c MalderMain.cpp
MalderMain.cpp:225:41: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
       pars.use_naive_algo, fit_starts[r]/*fit_start_dis*//*,*/ /*fits_all_starts_refs[r],
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/cctype:42:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/bits/localefwd.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/ios:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from MalderMain.cpp:9:
CorrJack.hpp:26:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
     CorrJack(int _C, const std::vector <std::string> &_ids);
                  ^
MalderMain.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
MalderMain.cpp:339:24: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
      for (int i = 0; i < allpairs.size(); i++) {
                        ^
MalderMain.cpp:345:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int i = 0; i < allpairs.size(); i++) pairs2use.push_back(allpairs[i]);
                           ^
MalderMain.cpp:348:23: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int i = 0; i < pairs2use.size(); i++){
                       ^
MalderMain.cpp:318:12: warning: unused variable ‘mult_hyp_corr’ [-Wunused-variable]
     double mult_hyp_corr = alder.compute_mult_hyp_corr(vector <bool> (num_ref_freqs, true));
            ^
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'MalderMain.o' failed
make: *** [MalderMain.o] Error 1
```

it looks like the errors are well located, but since I'm newbie, I don't know what to do to resolve....

and here's the surrounding lines to CorrJack.hpp

```
class CorrJack {

    const int C; // number of chromosomes on which to jackknife
    const std::vector <std::string> &jack_ind_ids; // labels of left-out chroms for output purposes
    // central = true for usual corr, false for non-zeroed
    std::pair <double, double> jackknife_corr(bool central);

  public:
    std::vector <Corr> data;

    CorrJack(int _C, const std::vector <std::string> &_ids);

    std::pair <double, double> jackknife_corr(void);
    std::pair <double, double> jackknife_cos(void);
    std::pair <double, double> jackknife_cos_polyache_denom(const CorrJack &test_data,
                                const CorrJack &ref_data);
    std::pair <double, double> jackknife_x2_avg(void);
    double tot_count(void);
    double tot_sum_x2(void);
  };
```

Comment: As you noticed, the error seems to revolve around CorrJack.hpp, line 26. Can you add the code of that line and a couple surrounding lines to your question?

Comment: Hi Marcus, I added the surrounding lines on CorrJack.hpp
THank you very much for your help.

Comment: This error could even be caused by a missing parenthesis , comma or semicolon farther up the file. Try to comment out line 26 and see if it fixes the error or if the compiler complains about some other line above it.

Comment: Hi farhan.. Thanks for your comment. So ..... what should I do with the line 26? added ',' or '...' before the "_C"? I'm so sorry, newbie here...